# parallel forking without Parallel::ForkManager?

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

is there a way to simply fork into i.g. 4 threads and check the states of the childs during a while loop? I read something about SIGCHLD (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) but I'm not familiar with this stuff and don't know how to use this. Btw. there is no reason not to use Parallel::ForkManager, I am just interested... and tried something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw/ WNOHANG /;
my @a = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 );
my @childs;
$#childs=4;

foreach my $a (@a){
    my $add=0;
    while(!$add){
        $add=0;
        foreach(0..$#childs){
            next if defined $childs[$_] && $childs[$_]!=0;
            $add=1;
            my $pid=fork();
            if ($pid == 0){
                &process($a);       
                exit;
            } else {    
                $childs[$_]=$pid;
                waitpid($pid,WNOHANG);              
            }           
        }
    }
}

sub process(){
    my $x = shift;  
    sleep(int(rand(10)));
    print $x."\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes. Just check the return value of `waitpid`.

Comment: Is there? Of course yes. You can basically re-implement ForkManager, or at least a simple subset of its functionality. Be aware that you need to concern yourself with harvesting zombie processes.

Comment: mh where do I need to check for waitpid? I changed this line: `next if defined $childs[$_] && waitpid($childs[$_],WNOHANG)!=0;` Sry for this maybe silly querstion, but I startet today working with forks...

Comment: What is your code suppose to do??

Comment: (Don't use `$a`. It's more or less a special variable for `sort`.)

Comment: just run 4 parallel threads of a bigger set of jobs and add a new thread into `@childs` if one finishes

Comment: if you were using threads before, take a look at drop in replacement but with forks http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/forks-0.34/lib/forks.pm#NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't look anything like the code you'd be using if you used F::PM, so that should have raised a red flag!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( _exit );

sub process {
   my ($job) = @_;
   sleep(1+int(rand(4)));
   print("$job\n");
}
```

```
my $max_children = 4;
my %children;

for my $job (0..9) {
   # Wait for the number of children to be less than the max.
   while (keys(%children) >= $max_children) {
      my $pid = wait();
      delete $children{$pid};
   }

   # Start a new child.
   if (my $pid = fork()) {
      # In parent
      ++$children{$pid};
   } else {
      # In child
      process($job);
      _exit(0);
   }
}

# Wait for remaining children to finish.
while (keys(%children)) {
   my $pid = wait();
   delete $children{$pid};
}
```

This is basically a simplified version of P::FM and user code combined.

Comment: ah ok thanks for your example. now I know what to do. Actually I used threads but get segmentation faults during the last join command and therefor searched for other solutions like forks.

Comment: Or you could try upgrading your Perl. Or you could use `use forks;` which looks just like `use threads;`, but is a reimplementation that uses processes instead of threads.

Comment: You don't need special permissions to install Perl. I use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to manage multiple installs, even. If you're a dev, having your own install of Perl (as opposed to the system's) is useful, and the ability to test with multiple versions of Perl can be even more so.